# ActivityNotFoundException when trying to call an activity from another project

Tags: android, android-activity, package

I'm trying to use another project I already have in my main project but when I call the activity from it, I get the `ActivityNotFoundException: have you declared this activity in your androidManifest?`. This is what i've done :

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.GCM.pushnotifications","com.GCM.pushnotifications.RegisterActivity");

intent.setComponent(cName);         
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the manifest :

```
 <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What am i doing wrong? this is what I found on the net.

Comment: use the package namealong with activity name for android name="com.GCM.psuchnotifications.RegisterActivity. and action tag and try.

Comment: already tried that but still the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide the activity class name as the second parameter of `ComponentName`

Change this

```
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.GCM.pushnotifications","com.GCM.pushnotifications.RegisterActivity");
```

to

```
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.GCM.pushnotifications","RegisterActivity");
```